# Webpack refresh tab instead of starting new tab

Tags: javascript, webpack

How do I configure webpack to refresh the tab `http://localhost:4545/` if it already exists, instead of creating a new `http://localhost:4545/` tab every time I run `npm start`?

Current webpack configurations: https://github.com/James2516/hot-reload

Comment: I don't think we can do that I guess

Answer (score 2):

in pre configuration of webpcak already exists scripts/start.js

`const openBrowser = require('react-dev-utils/openBrowser')`

this file make your app open automatically every time you make your server start.
This is a solution :)